# Parse string to floating point number

Tags: javascript, react-native, floating-point

I'm struggling trying to parse some string that I'm reading from a txt file. When I parse it using parseFloat() it doesn't work as expected, for example when I log a "45.64" parsed to float it shows: 45.63999938964844.
This is my code:

```
  const linesProd = productosTxt.split(/\r?\n/);
  var productosObject = { "Productos": [] };
  linesProd.forEach(line => {
    const fields = line.split("|");
    
    if (fields[0]){
      console.log(fields[0])
      console.log(typeof(fields[5]))
      var fieldsObject = {
        productId: fields[0],
        id: fields[1],
        name: fields[2],
        cost: Number.parseFloat(fields[3]),
        price1: Number.parseFloat(fields[4]),
        price2: Number.parseFloat(fields[5]),
      };
      
      productosObject = { ...productosObject, "Productos": [...productosObject.Productos, fieldsObject] };
    }
  });
```

Those fields (cost, price1, price2) are suposed to save those fields from my txt file in number format. The lines in the txt file look something like this:

```
A1|1|name1|50.5|70|80

A2|2|name2|25.25|35.6|90.15
```

I already took a look at some posts here but can't find a proper answer

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Edit1:
Log of the fields in the array (changed some variable names but they are likely the same so you can see)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **+yourString** instead

```
  const linesProd = productosTxt.split(/\r?\n/);
  var productosObject = { "Productos": [] };
  linesProd.forEach(line => {
    const fields = line.split("|");
    
    if (fields[0]){
      console.log(fields[0])
      console.log(typeof(fields[5]))
      var fieldsObject = {
        productId: fields[0],
        id: fields[1],
        name: fields[2],
        cost: +fields[3],
        price1: +fields[4],
        price2: +fields[5],
      };
      
      productosObject = { ...productosObject, "Productos": [...productosObject.Productos, fieldsObject] };
    }
  });
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it keeps saving the numbers in an unexpected way: "35.94" got converted into 35.939998626708984

Comment: That's weird, I tried that on my pc and worked ok, could you log the fields array and add it to the question ?

Comment: Done, i added a picture of the log

Comment: Log this: console.log(+"35.94") and console.log(+` ${fields[3]} `) Just to check is something is wrong with the numbers from the txt

Comment: Omg I just logged the field on the console and it's correct, but when it´s assigned is when the value messes up, what could it be?

Comment: Edit2: I found the problem, if I log a fieldObject after it's created it has the expected values. The problem is when I add it to the database (realm database) where the values mess up

Comment: Oh :o Nice, so, I don't know anything about that db, is a db for mobiles right ? It has some schema definition or configurations to look ? Pls add the info to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const linesProd = productosTxt.split(/\r?\n/);
var productosObject = { Productos: [] };
linesProd.forEach((line) => {
  const fields = line.split("|");

  if (fields[0]) {
    console.log(fields[0]);
    console.log(typeof fields[5]);
    var fieldsObject = {
      productId: fields[0],
      id: fields[1],
      name: fields[2],
      cost: Number.parseFloat(fields[3]).toFixed(2),
      price1: Number.parseFloat(fields[4]).toFixed(2),
      price2: Number.parseFloat(fields[5]).toFixed(2),
    };

    productosObject = { ...productosObject, Productos: [...productosObject.Productos, fieldsObject] };
  }
});
```

Fix the parsing to two decimal places, that should give you the number you expect.

Comment: The problem with that is i have to keep those properties as numbers, when you use tofixed it returns a string